# "Error: timeout of 600000ms exceeded" in github build with ghost inspector tests

Tags: github, ghost-inspector

I have the below error in github build with ghost inspector tests

> "Error: timeout of 600000ms exceeded"

[image]

I tried `maxTimeout` in git build `.yml` file. But it's not working.

https://ghostinspector.com/docs/integration/github-actions/

If anyone knows this solution share it with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of changing the concurrency in the ghostinpector, you can use the ghostinprctor-cli for run the git actions.

Ex:

https://ghostinspector.com/docs/api/cli/

```
- uses: docker://ghostinspector/cli
        with:
          args: suite execute ${{ secrets.GI_SUITE }} \
              --apiKey ${{ secrets.GI_API_KEY }} \
              --errorOnFail
```

`secrets.GI_SUITE` and `secrets.GI_API_KEY` are the ghostinspector API and SUITE keys. you can get those from the ghostinspector settings

`secrets` and the github secrets https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets

Answer (score 0):

The above issue has based on concurrency limitations.

Previously I used 25 tests that not working.

Now I changed that 50 tests. Now, `maxTimeout=600000ms` is working correctly for me.

[image]